# VBA loop through XML nodes

Tags: xml, vba, excel

Hello I am trying to loop between nodes from an xml but for some reason I am only getting the first node any ideas would be greatly appreciated! 
    XML:

```
<root>
          <AC>
           <answer id ="c1"> 
              blue
           </answer>
           <answer id ="c1"> 
              blue
           </answer>
</root>
```

VBA Code:

```
     Set ques = getQues(qName) 'ques is in CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument") format

            Set nodes = ques.SelectNodes("/root/AC")
            For Each node In nodes
                MsgBox (node.SelectSingleNode("answer").Text)
                Cells(i + 1, j).Value = node.SelectSingleNode("answer").Text
            Next node
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed - missing the closing `</AC>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `selectnodes` is only selecting the `AC` node: it looks like you really want to select the collection of `answer` nodes -

```
Sub Tester()

Dim d As New MSXML2.DOMDocument
Dim nodes, nd

    d.LoadXML Range("A1").Value

    Set nodes = d.SelectNodes("/root/AC/answer")
    For Each nd In nodes
        Debug.Print nd.getAttribute("id"), nd.Text
    Next nd

End Sub
```